# Spring-Data projections. The correct way?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data

In my attempt of using JPA with a legacy database, I've came to the conclusion I need to obtain a subset of my huge 50-60 column tables columns, since the queries generated by one single select sentence can be around 4 or 5 sheets of paper long with a endless number of joins.

I am wondering, how you experts, face this problem related mainly to performance and efficency, but also with the application's design and how you do structure your project, entities, pojos etc in a reasonable way.

- About the class containing the result:

  - Is it OK to use the full entity class to return 2 or 3 columns from a table?
  - Would you use a POJO in a DTO-fashioned way?
  - Or a shortened version of the entity referncing the same table?
- How would this interact with the dependent layers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd use Spring's JDBC template:
https://spring.io/guides/gs/relational-data-access/

Answer (score 1):

I would use @Query and custom code the query with a DTO representing the model needed, saves memory, also prefer Spring-Data-JDBC over JPA